# Vector layer with "GEOM_POSSIBLE_NAMES" not working when source as *file*

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-3

I have two CSV files having the below content.

*pnt as WKT.csv*:

```
sl,wkt
1, POINT(50.0 50.0)
```

*pnt as PNT.csv*:

```
sl,pnt    
1, POINT(50.0 50.0)
```

The difference in both the file is column name in the geometry field (`wkt`, `pnt`).

Adding the file "pnt as WKT.csv" as "Add Vector Layer" with "GEOM_POSSIBLE_NAMES" as `pnt, wkt` works fine.

But, adding the file "pnt as PNT.csv" as "Add Vector Layer" with "GEOM_POSSIBLE_NAMES" as `pnt, wkt` doesn't seem to work. I am able to select "zoom to layer" which focus the exact point but the "Symbology" is not visible and the `$geometry` shows NULL.

QGIS Version - 3.16.14-Hannover

[image: With Both the layers Visible]

[image: After Disabling the 'pnt as WKY' layer]

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use "Add Delimited Text Layer"?

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz Yes, Adding as Delimited  text layer doesn't have editing option. "Vector" layer have the edit option.

Comment: No problem in QGIS 3.22.2. But, yes, there is a problem in 3.16.14

Answer (score 5):

Adding as file is not a problem in QGIS 3.22.2. Obviously there is a problem in QGIS 3.16.14.

I found a solution which doesn't add from file, but folder, in v3.16.

- Copy all CSVs to a folder.
- Select "Directory" in "Data Source Manage | Vector" window.

[image]

Comment: I have already tested out as "Directory" option and it worked, the issue is only as "File" option. Presently, tested the same in 3.22.2 and it worked fine. May be a bug in version 3.16. Thanks you very much for your help bro.

Comment: It also has an error (OGR error syncing to disk: Error while creating ~pnt as PNT.csv_ogr_tmp.csv) while editing and saving the feature when layer "geometry" column name is not mentioned "wkt". (Version 3.22.2)